# Carousel not responding to screen size as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning Bootstrap 3 and have a simple page I am working on that only consist of a top nav bar, carousel, and footer.

The page looks OK at desktop size. When it shrinks to mobile size I have too much white space. If I have to add more content to fill it I will but is there an alternative to avoid doing that. I like the simpleness with just the carousel.

Is there a way to make it look nice on a mobile the way I have it?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-12 column">
            <!-- Fixed navbar -->
            <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                        </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <br />
    <!-- Begin page content -->
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-12 column">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-491568">
                <!-- <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-491568">
                    </li>
                    <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-491568">
                    </li>
                    <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-491568">
                    </li>
                </ol> -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
                        <!--<div class="carousel-caption">
                             <h2>NEW Client!</h2>
                            <p></p>
                        </div> --></div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
                        <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4>
                            <p></p>
                    </div> --></div>
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
                        <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>
                            <p> </p>
                        </div> --></div>
                </div> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-491568" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-491568" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-12 column">
            <div id="footer">
                <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
                    <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
                        <!--<p class="footer-block">Footer</p> -->
                        <p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-1x">&nbsp;Questions?</i></a> | <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-1x">&nbsp;(740) 564-9876</i>

                        </p>
                        <p>Copy Here</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-text pull-right"> <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="#" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                    </a>
 <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin" href="#" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                    </a>
 <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="#" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5krygmfd/)**

Comment: Off topic: One `.container` element is usually adequate.

Comment: The carousel is the height it is because of the aspect ratio of the elements you're using. You'd have to either use taller images, or use the images as backgrounds and crop them using `background-size: cover`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am sure I will need to add more content to fill the white space. Trying to understand the whole grid info.

Comment: Off topic 2: Don't use break tags for layout. Divs are block-level by default, so you shouldn't need them. If you're just adding space, use CSS margin or padding.

Comment: Re: your comment... Content drives layout, not vice versa. Maybe a carousel isn't the right delivery mechanism for your content.

Comment: Is cropping the images an option for you? I'll be happy to demo that technique.

Comment: thanks for the info. I may need to change it up some.

Comment: isherwood, if you think it will help, please demo

Comment: Comments added. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5krygmfd/4/

Comment: I think it works better with fluid containers: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5krygmfd/5

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to modify the classic carousel html script using a background image and adjusting the size in your css file accordingly.

here you will find an html example:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Header Carousel -->
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>

        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
         <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
             <div class="item active">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('https://placeimg.com/1440/810/any');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                  <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('https://placeimg.com/1440/810/any');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                  <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('https://placeimg.com/1440/810/any');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

and your css example code:

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
/* -------carousel slides----*/
 .carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
      background-image: none;  
  }        
.carousel-indicators {
  bottom:-50px;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
   border-color: #C0C0C0;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
.carousel-inner {
   margin-bottom:50px;
}
.carousel .item{
    height: 400px;
}
.item img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 400px;
}
.carousel .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/88GvagC4pb#)